# El background se repite en el modo responsive

Tags: html, css

Estoy teniendo un problema con mi página web, al querer adaptarla a la resolución 991px, sucede que el background se repite de forma vertical. La etiqueta `background-size: cover;` ya esta colocada en el CSS.

[image: webpage sin responsive]
[image: webpage en modo responsive]

- Al hacer Zoom, no sucede esto con el background. De hecho se aplica la regla que puse dentro del modo responsivo.
- También he probado agregar la etiqueta mencionada arriba en el responsive.css.

**styles.css**

```
body {
/* Background */
background: url(../images/background.png);
background-size: cover;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;

/* Animations */
animation: fadeInAnimation ease 4s;
}

.gameTitle {
border: 1px solid red;
width: 75%;
margin: 10% auto auto 1%;
}

.gameTitle h1 {
font-family: "All The Way To The Sun";
font-size: 144px;
color: #E1E0E0;
}
```

**responsive.css**

```
.gameTitle h1 {
color: red;
font-size: 80px;
}
```

Comment: Prueba añadir la propiedad `background-repeat: no-repeat;` a body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución que encontre fue poner el fondo en el html y no en body, además de agregar la etiqueta `background-repeat`.

```
html {
  background: url(../images/background.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
```